# Nissan sentra 1600 1999 model

Tags: nissan, sentra

[image]

Hi i am new to cars and this box is loose. Where does it come and what does it do? It has a few loose cables atached looks like its a positive and negative

Nissan sentra 1600 1999

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

That is a relay, could be for horn or headlights, heated rear window, fog lights, in fact anything that uses a high current.

Secure it properly.